# vuejs laravel Layouts - Assets

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js

please I try to make my first vuejs - laravel application, 
and I get a trouble with layouts and assets, this is my code:

Here i try to detect the layout from route, it dosen't work very well, because when i refresh the page, it chage the main layout first and after go the layout needed

**app.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="$route.meta.layout == 'front'">
            <frontLayout></frontLayout>
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="$route.meta.layout == 'admin'">
            <adminLayout></adminLayout>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <mainLayout></mainLayout>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    let frontLayout = require('./layouts/frontLayout.vue');
    let mainLayout = require('./layouts/mainLayout.vue');

    import {mapState} from 'vuex'

    export default {
        components:{frontLayout,mainLayout},
        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                userStore: state => state.userStore
            })
        },
        created(){
            console.log('app vue')
        }
    }
</script>
```

For the asset after setting the webpack laravel-mix like this:

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.combine(['resources/assets/front/css/*','resources/assets/front/plugin-css/*','resources/assets/front/style.css'], 'public/css/front.css')
    .options({
      processCssUrls: false,
    });
mix.combine(['resources/assets/front/script/*','resources/assets/front/plugin-script/*'], 'public/js/front.js')
    .options({
      processCssUrls: false,
    });
```

I try to import the front.css file in the frontLayout.vue when it was loaded like this:

**frontLayout.vue**

```
<template></template>
<script>

    export default {

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    @import '../../../../public/css/front.css';
</style>
```

But it dosen't work always ! any help please. Thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is the import failing? Do you get any kind of message in your console?

Comment: The import of style doesn't work, i dont get any message in console